# make filter based on data from localstorage in the filter function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I'm new with the Ionic-angular.js, I hope that someone will help me to resolve this problem

First, here is the code

**favorites.html**

```
  ...
<ion-item ng-repeat="dish in dishes | favoriteFilter:favorites" href="#/app/menu/{{dish.id}}" class="item-thumbnail-left" on-swipe-left="deleteFavorite(dish.id)">
        <img ng-src="{{baseURL+dish.image}}" on-swipe-left="deleteFavorite(dish.id)">
        <h2>{{dish.name}}
        <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled"
          ng-click="deleteFavorite(dish.id)">
        </ion-delete-button>
      </ion-item>
...
```

**services.js**

```
.factory('favoriteFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function ($resource, baseURL) {
        var favFac = {};
        var favorites = [];

        favFac.addToFavorites = function (index) {
            for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
                if (favorites[i].id == index)
                    return;
            }
            favorites.push({id: index});
        };

        favFac.deleteFromFavorites = function (index) {
            for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
                if (favorites[i].id == index) {
                    favorites.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        favFac.getFavorites = function () {
            return favorites;
        };

        return favFac;
        }])

    .factory('$localStorage', ['$window', function($window) {
        return {
        store: function(key, value) {
          $window.localStorage[key] = value;
        },
        get: function(key, defaultValue) {
          return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
        },
        storeObject: function(key, value) {
          $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
        },
        getObject: function(key,defaultValue) {
          return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue);
        }
        //removeItem: function(key){
        //    $window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
        //}
      }
```

**controller.js**

```
.filter('favoriteFilter', 'localStorage', function (localStorage) {

            if(localStorage.getItem('favorites')!=undefined)
                {
                    var out = [];
                    return out;
                }
            else{
                return function (dishes) {
                var old_favorite = JSON.parse($localStorage.get('favorites'));
                var leng = Object.keys(old_favorite).length;
                console.log(leng);

                var out = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < dishes.length; j++) {
                        if (dishes[j].id === favorites[i].id)
                            out.push(dishes[j]);
                    }
                }
                return out;
                }}
});
```

For the example, there was an array inside the localstorage like this

```
Key : favorites
value : [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":0}]
```

So, the logic is, I compare the ID between from database and the localstorage based on the ID with the filter function

If the ID is same, so the data from the database gonna push it into the favorites menu.

but, it couldn't show in the favorites menu, and when I checked on the console, it said that

> [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

Did I make something wrong on here? Or maybe I put a wrong method on here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you present seems to be a syntax problem. You are missing the array brackets.

```
.filter('favoriteFilter', ['$localStorage', function (localStorage) {

        if(localStorage.getItem('favorites')!=undefined)
        {
            var out = [];
            return out;
        }
        else
        {
            return function (dishes) {
                var old_favorite = JSON.parse($localStorage.get('favorites'));
                var leng = Object.keys(old_favorite).length;
                console.log(leng);

                var out = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < dishes.length; j++) {
                        if (dishes[j].id === favorites[i].id)
                            out.push(dishes[j]);
                    }
                }
                return out;
            }
        };
}]);
```

I didn't check your logic function, this will be the answer to solve your error.

Comment: oh, thank you very much! I can retrieve the array from local storage right now.
But, after that, there is some error, something like this
"TypeError: v3 is not a function"
Do you know what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach:

As you already have addToFavorites and deleteFromFavorites functions, all you have to do is simply follow these 3 steps:

1. When defining you 'favorites' array, simply assign it as follows: 
   var favorites = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['favorites'] || []);
2. In your addToFavorites function, after you push the added item to your array, add: window.localStorage['favorites'] = JSON.stringify(favorites);
3. In your deleteFromFavorites function, after you splice your array, add: window.localStorage['favorites'] = JSON.stringify(favorites);

You should be good to go with these three super simple steps!